# How to assign the access civiMember permission

Tags: civimember, permissions

I would like to use civimember.
I clicked the membership tab, but nothing opened.
No add membership appeared.
Do I need to assign the access CiviMember permission? And how do I manage to assign?

Comment: Hi and welcome Uta. It could help to compare with what you see at https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org to make sure you are seeing what 'should' show. I think if you are seeing the Membership Tab then probably permissions are set fine (if not they would be in Drupal > People > Permissions (ps I have never used Spark version)

Comment: Would be useful to know your environment and I don't see anything in the question to say Spark or even Drupal. Are you in the admin group for CiviCRM? If you set it up you will be. If not, check with the person who set it up.